# Scrape sub elements in tables which cannot found in html but only in Chrome>F12>Element

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-chrome, web-scraping

I have tried to scrape scoring/event time and also player name http://en.gooooal.com/soccer/analysis/8401/events_840182.html.However cannot work.

```
require(RCurl);
require(XML);
lnk = "http://en.gooooal.com/soccer/analysis/8401/events_840182.html";
doc = htmlTreeParse(lnk,useInternalNodes=TRUE);
x = unlist(xpathApply(doc, "//table/tr/td"));
```

normal html page doesn't show the details of the table contents.
the nodes only can get from

>>> open Chrome >>> click F12 >>> click Element

Can someone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The table is dynamically generated, probably by function `_g_event.LoadEvent(840182)`. Alternatively to mimicking a javascript-enabled browser, you could try your luck inspecting the source code for this function and build a POST/GET query to read the data from their database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reload the page while Chrome developer tools are active, you can see that real data is fetched via XHR from `http://en.gooooal.com/soccer/analysis/8401/goal_840182.js?GmFEjC8MND`. This URL contains event id `840182` which you can scrape from the page. The part after `?` *seems* to be just a way to circumvent browser caching. `8401`, again, *seems* to be just first digits of the id.

So, you can load the original page, construct the second URL, and get real data from there.

Anyway... In most cases it's a morally questionalble practice to scrape data from web sites. I hope you know what you're doing :)

Comment: May I know how to do as http://en.gooooal.com/soccer/analysis/8401/goal_840182.js?GmFEjC8MND only show couples of digits and some players' name?

Comment: @ケンジリュスケ No idea, honestly. You have to reverse-engineer their data format. Javascript source of that page may help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the content was inserted asynchronously using javascript, so using Curl won't help you there.

You'll need a headless browser which can actually parse and execute javascript (If you know ruby you could start looking for the cucumber-selenium-chromedriver combo), or maybe just use your browser with greasemonkey/tampermonkey to actually mimic a real user browsing the score scraping.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use Chrome's add-on "Scraper", however it can just scrape the words but no icon, so I cant different the type of event. Moreover its gonna be manually scrape match-by-match...

Answer (score 1):

The contents are probably generated (by Javascript, like from an ajax call) after loading the (HTML) page. You can check that by loading the page in Chrome after disabling Javascript.

I don't think you can instruct RCurl to execute Javascript...